# Quantitatively define "small gradient" when checking convergence

Tags: convergence, gradient-descent

When checking if a gradient descent (GD) has reached a minimum, it's a common practice to check the gradient of the cost function at the final iterate (also one might check if the Hessian is positive semi-definite).

Since this is a numerical method performed on a finite precision machine, the gradient cannot be completely equal to zero. What is a good practice to define a "small enough gradient" that indicates that the GD has converged?

Currently, I am saying that the GD has converged when
$$\alpha \max_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial w_{i}}\leq10^{-7}$$
where $\alpha$ is a learning rate, $f$ is a cost function, $w_{i}$ is a parameter being optimized. $10^{-7}$ is completely arbitrary. I think I should normalize the left handside by some norm of $w$, but I am not sure if this is the right direction.

Comment: Another strategy is to terminate if the norm of the gradient is too small $\left\| \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} \right\| < \epsilon$, since we know the gradient is a zero vector at a stationary point.